# Find the last record based on a attribute of a table

Tags: laravel-4

In laravel, I create a migration table named 'timelogs'. Assumed that, this table have three column id,userid,value. 'id' is primary key and have auto increment property , 'userid' is foreign key. I insert data 1,2,2,2,2 and 3,4,5,6,7 for'userid' and 'value' field respectively.

Now I want to find last inserted record.Such as userid = 2 and value = 7.Here userid field contain different user's id. I want to find specific user's last record. How can I do this without using primary key?

Comment: is this userid value is, in increment order like, first inserted userid would 3, next inserted userid would be 4 and so on.

Comment: No it's not in incremented order.And also not unique.It will contain duplicate value.

Comment: why not using primary key, it would be far easier

Comment: I know that. But here userid field contain different user's id. I want to find specific user's last record.

Comment: temporary solution, use one more extra field for, user_id_insertcount auto-incremental for last inserted record in userid.

Comment: It will give the last record of the table, not for specific user's last record. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

$last_record = DB::table('timelogs')->where('userid', $user_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
//var_dump($last_record);